# Adding custom menu on right click to project in solution explorer (Visual studio 2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have been trying to add another option in the right click menu (just above Add references) to build some come packages.

I am using VSPackaging (VS 2010) for this. The problem is I am not able to get the correct Guid with which I can get the button in its right place.

I tried the following:

```
<Menu guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_ITEMNODE" priority="0x0000" type="Context">
```

but this only gets as far as getting a control at an item level and not at the project level.

Answer (score 2):

May be this is too old thread but in case if someone reach here you can find the answer

We have to use a different Id if we have to add a new menu item to the Project level content menu

Please replace IDM_VS_CTXT_ITEMNOD with **IDM_VS_CTXT_PROJNODE**

You can follow a different approach which is the most suitable method if you don't know the Id for a particular menu.

Please check the link to see the solution
[VSIX: Adding a Menu Item to the Visual Studio Editor Context Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759396/vsix-adding-a-menu-item-to-the-visual-studio-editor-context-menu)

Comment: How about multiple projects?

Answer (score 0):

I tried out the combination of {guidSHLMainMenu, IDG_VS_CTXT_PROJECT_ADD} with priority set to 0x2000 and it worked.