# Visual Studio Extensions: Adding element to the Code Editor ContextMenu

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, add-on

I'm trying to  add a new element to the Visual Studio 2017 Context Menu. I managed to add an element to the TOOLS menu with the following code:

```
<Button guid="guidRandomCommandPackageCmdSet" id="RandomCommandId" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDG_VS_TOOLS_EXT_TOOLS" />
    <Icon guid="exclamationIcon" id="exclamationIcon1" />
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>Random Text</ButtonText>
    </Strings>
  </Button>
```

which is registered in

```
<GuidSymbol name="guidRandomCommandPackageCmdSet" value="{47122772-c66f-48f3-b10b-dbbb66da120d}">
     .
     .
  <IDSymbol name="RandomCommandId" value="0x0100" />
</GuidSymbol>
```

I tried to follow a similar fashion, so I defined a new `Button` in `Buttons`:

```
 <Button guid="guidRandomCommandPackageCmdSet" id="ToDoList" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_CODEWIN"/>
    <Icon guid="exclamationIcon" id="exclamationIcon1" />
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>Add TODO list</ButtonText>
    </Strings>
  </Button>with the ID symbol
```

with the ID registerd in GuidSymbols

```
  <IDSymbol name="ToDoList" value="0x106" />
```

But the button does not show up in the context menu, when I run the project. I tried to follow the suggestions of [VSIX: Adding a Menu Item to the Visual Studio Editor Context Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759396/vsix-adding-a-menu-item-to-the-visual-studio-editor-context-menu) but none of the suggestions seems to work for me.
I never tried to create a VS add-on before, so I welcome any suggestions. Is it possible that the method changed in VS 2017?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually, I managed to get it working. It seems that while for MENU items that show up either as a separate menu or belonging to a menu like TOOLS, it is enough to have only a `Button` with the parent set to the appropriate constant menu element string as defined at [GUIDs and IDs of Visual Studio Menus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc826118.aspx).

For `ContextMenu` elements, however, I needed to have an element in `Groups`:

```
<Group guid="guidRandomCommandPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_CODEWIN" />
  </Group>
```

This has the `ContextMenu` as its `Parent`. Then, I created a `CustomCommand` that auto-generates a `Button` with it and I modified this `Button` to have the `Group` element as its`Parent`:
`
    
        
        
        
           Add TODO list

This is the result with the added button hovered over:

[image: Button on Context Menu]

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I have been searching for at least an hour!