# Context Menu Visual Studio Extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I need help to find the command which allows an Command in Visual Studio to add a option to the
Coding Interface Context Menu , so that if you right click on an class you would be able to use the Extension

Comment: You can reference the "Extend Menus and Commands" section on the MS Docs site -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extending-menus-and-commands?view=vs-2022

Comment: You can see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759396/vsix-adding-a-menu-item-to-the-visual-studio-editor-context-menu) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45988749/visual-studio-extensions-adding-element-to-the-code-editor-contextmenu), hope these can help you.