# How can I create an SSMS extension that opens from the execution plan window?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-extensions, ssms-18

I would like to create an SQL Server Management Studio v18 extension that opens from the execution plan window. I believe that this is technically possible because there is a [third party tool](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer) that already does this:

[image]

So far, I've been able to create a basic extension in SSMS v18 using the guide located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55661806/how-to-create-an-extension-for-ssms-2019-v18). I was also able to move the placement of the button by referencing the IDs in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/guids-and-ids-of-visual-studio-menus?view=vs-2022). However, I can't figure out how to modify the .vsct file in order to move my button to be within the execution plan window.

How can I create an SSMS extension that opens from the execution plan window?

Comment: This is a superbly useful question and answer, that is clearly on-topic for [so].

Comment: I suggest keeping in mind that Azure Data Studio is the tool of the future and uses more modern tools to build extensions

Comment: Also, though, Azure Data Tools is terrible.

Comment: Last time I looked at it it was using the same web project as "paste the plan" uses to show execution plans which is massively inferior to SSMS. Does look like maybe things have moved on since then though https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/query-plan-viewer?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @HannahVernon Azure Data Studio is certainly a different experience and not well suited to on prem. Yes it's also still quite immature. It does have a bunch of features that SSMS doesn't have and it's still a kinda bloat free. If you mean SQL Server Data Tools, yes that is definitely terrible!

Comment: Opinions aside, ADS has a few great features, such as run-booking, but it is essentially unusable as an enterprise management tool.  Personally, I would prefer to see Microsoft not intentionally fragment its own market, but they're known for shooting themselves in the leg, then amputating the good leg in spite.  SSDT, which I use every day in a CI/CD development environment works very well, but does need some work.

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out.

[image]

In the `<Symbols>` element of the *.vsct file add

```
<GuidSymbol name="foo1" value="{33F13AC3-80BB-4ECB-85BC-225435603A5E}">
  <IDSymbol name="foo2" value="0x0080"/>
</GuidSymbol>
```

Then change

```
<Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS"/>
```

to

```
<Parent guid="foo1" id="foo2"/>
```

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759396/vsix-adding-a-menu-item-to-the-visual-studio-editor-context-menu/31769170#31769170).

(You may also want to set the `priority` on the parent `<Group` element to `0x0001` if eager to see your extension higher up in the menu)

My mechanism for determining the magic Guid was initially quite laborious and is in the edit history for this Answer but a somewhat less laborious method would be to do set the registry key

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\18.0_IsoShell\General]
"EnableVSIPLogging"=dword:00000001
```

And then open SSMS, get an execution plan and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right click to bring up a message box as below (128 decimal is `0x80`).

[image]

## Now what?

It wasn't immediately apparent to me how to do anything useful inside the menu click event so I think it is informative to add an example.

As a POC I tried to colour nodes with a subtree cost above a threshold and/or where the underlying execution plan operators met some potentially problematic conditions.

[image]

For this I changed the code in the `Execute` method in the template generated code to

```
private void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();

    Dictionary<string, Color> coloringRules = new Dictionary<string, Color>
    {
        [@".//ns:Intrinsic[@FunctionName = ""GetRangeThroughConvert""]"] = Color.Yellow,
        [@".//ns:Intrinsic[@FunctionName = ""GetRangeWithMismatchedTypes""]"] = Color.MediumPurple
    };

    ProofOfConcept.ColorInterestingNodes(coloringRules, costThreshold: 0.0032831);
}
```

this relies on the following nested class

```
private class ProofOfConcept
{
    private const string ShowPlanControlTypeFullName = "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ShowPlan.ShowPlanControl";
    private const string GraphControlTypeFullName = "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.ShowPlan.GraphControl";
    private const string ShowPlanNamespaceUri = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan";
    private static readonly XNamespace ns = ShowPlanNamespaceUri;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetFocus();

    public static void ColorInterestingNodes(Dictionary<string, Color> coloringRules, double costThreshold)
    {
        IntPtr focus = GetFocus();

        Control activeControl = Control.FromChildHandle(focus);
        Control rootControl = FindRootControl(activeControl); 

        List <Control> graphControls = new List<Control>();

        FindAllDescendantControlsOfType(rootControl, graphControls, GraphControlTypeFullName);

        XElement[] qpElements = GetShowPlanXMLQueryPlans(rootControl);

        //TODO: More robust method of matching up the query plan XML elements with the display elements.
        //e.g. "Use database;" statement will show a graph in "estimated" plan but not "actual" - and not have a QueryPlan element in the XML
        if (graphControls.Count != qpElements.Count())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Mismatch between graph control count (" + graphControls.Count + ") and query plan count (" + qpElements.Count() + "). Exiting");
            return;
        }

        for (var index = 0; index < graphControls.Count; index++)
        {
            Control graphControl = graphControls[index];
            XElement qpElement = qpElements[index];

            Dictionary<int, Color> nodeBackgroundColors = GetNodeBackgroundColors(qpElement, coloringRules);

            foreach (dynamic item in ((dynamic)graphControl).Nodes)
            {
                var nodeId = item.NodeOriginal["NodeId"] ?? -1;

                if (item.NodeOriginal.Cost >= costThreshold)
                {
                    item.TextColor = Color.Red;
                    item.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
                    item.UseBackgroundColor = true;
                }

                if (nodeBackgroundColors.TryGetValue(nodeId, out Color color))
                {
                    item.BackgroundColor = color;
                    item.UseBackgroundColor = true;
                }
            }

            graphControl.Refresh();

        }
    }

    private static Dictionary<int, Color> GetNodeBackgroundColors(XElement queryPlan, Dictionary<string, Color> coloringRules)
    {
        var returnValue = new Dictionary<int, Color>();

        NameTable nt = new NameTable();
        XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
        namespaceManager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan");

        foreach (var coloringRule in coloringRules)
        {
            var foundElements = queryPlan.XPathSelectElements(coloringRule.Key, namespaceManager);

            foreach (var foundNode in foundElements)
            {
                var nodeId = foundNode.AncestorsAndSelf(ns + "RelOp").FirstOrDefault()?.Attribute("NodeId")?.Value;

                if (nodeId != null)
                {
                    returnValue[int.Parse(nodeId)] = coloringRule.Value;
                }
            }
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

    private static XElement[] GetShowPlanXMLQueryPlans(Control rootControl)
    {
        List<Control> showPlanControls = new List<Control>();

        FindAllDescendantControlsOfType(rootControl, showPlanControls, ShowPlanControlTypeFullName);

        Assembly sqlEditorsAssembly = Assembly.Load("SQLEditors");
        Type showPlanControlType = sqlEditorsAssembly.GetType(ShowPlanControlTypeFullName);

        MethodInfo GetShowPlanXmlMethod = showPlanControlType.GetMethod("GetShowPlanXml", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        string xplan = GetShowPlanXmlMethod.Invoke(showPlanControls[0], null) as string;

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xplan);

        return doc.Descendants(ns + "QueryPlan").ToArray();
    }

    private static Control FindRootControl(Control control)
    {
        while (control.Parent != null)
            control = control.Parent;

        return control;
    }

    private static void FindAllDescendantControlsOfType(Control control, List<Control>  graphControls, string typeFullName)
    {
        if (control.GetType().FullName == typeFullName)
            graphControls.Add(control);

        foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
            FindAllDescendantControlsOfType(child, graphControls, typeFullName);
    }

}
```